# ExtJS - How to add grid paging toolbar in ExtJS 6.2?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In ExtJS 6.2 modern, how do I add a grid paging?

On the documentation for 6.2 it doesn't give details: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.grid.plugin.PagingToolbar.html

Following more recent ExtJS documentation I tried:

```js
Ext.define('MyGrid', {
   extend       : 'Ext.grid.Grid',
   store        : 'mystore',
   plugins: {
      pagingtoolbar: true
   },
});
```

The above gives an error in ExtJS: `Error: [Ext.create] Invalid class name or alias 'null' specified, must be a non-empty string`.

Please see fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3gmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it should be:

```js
    plugins: [{
        type: 'pagingtoolbar'
    }],
```